# How to add custom resolvers to prisma cloud graphql backend?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, prisma

I am working on a react project, boosted via CRA. I am using prisma cloud, which generates basic queries, mutations etc. for me, which is great but not enough :(. I would like to know if I can add my custom resolvers to the ones already built in prisma-schema.js. If so, where and how can add them?

```
import { HttpLink } from "apollo-link-http";
import { InMemoryCache } from "apollo-cache-inmemory";

const client = new ApolloClient({
  // By default, this client will send queries to the
  //  `/graphql` endpoint on the same host
  // Pass the configuration option { uri: YOUR_GRAPHQL_API_URL } to the `HttpLink` to connect
  // to a different host
  link: new HttpLink({
    uri: "https://eu1.prisma.sh/xxx/xxx/dev"
  }),
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});

export default client;
```

My expectation is to be able to both
- add custom fields to current queries
- make custom queries.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add more resolvers to the Prisma generated schema.

If you want to add features on top of what Prisma generates, you need to follow the architecture found in the documentation:
[image: Prisma architecture]

I encourage your to read this page of the documentation, which should help you understand how to integrate Prisma in your project: https://www.prisma.io/docs/understand-prisma/prisma-basics-datamodel-client-and-server-fgz4/